# How to correctly handle errors in this effect?

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, ngrx-effects

I've written the Effect below to make requests for each item in the array, and when one fails, the error isn't handled and the observable stream completes resulting actions not triggering effects any further.

```
Effect:

@Effect() myEffect$ = this.actions$.pipe(
     ofType<myAction>(myActionTypes.myAction),
     mergeMapTo(this.store.select(getAnArray)),
     exhaustMap((request: any[]) => {
        return zip(...request.map(item => {
           return this.myService.myFunction(item).pipe(
              map(response => {
                 return this.store.dispatch(new MyActionSuccess(response))
              }),
              catchError(error => {
                 return Observable.of(new MyActionFailure(error));
              })
           )
        }))
     })
```

How do I handle the error in this case?

Comment: How do you know the error isn't handled?

Comment: Try moving the `catchError` into the `exhaustMap` pipe.